# how to fix the data grid view can't load the records

Tags: c#, visual-studio

I have 2 different forms 1st is for my data grid view 2nd is for adding information now after I add the info I, want to load the records to my data grid view automatically after I saved the info

```
public partial class PERSONAL_DETAILS_FRM : Form
{
    SqlConnection con;
    SqlCommand cmd;
    SqlDataReader dr;
    ConnectionDB db = new ConnectionDB();
    public PERSONAL_DETAILS_FRM()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        con = new SqlConnection(db.Getconnection());
    }

    private DataGridView personal_dgv = new DataGridView();
    public void LoadDataGrid()
    {
        try
        {
            con.Open();
            using (cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM Personal_info", con))
            {
                using (dr = cmd.ExecuteReader())
                {
                    personal_dgv.Rows.Clear();

                    while (dr.Read())
                    {
                        personal_dgv.Rows.Add(
                            dr["EmployeeID"].ToString(),
                            dr["LastName"].ToString(),
                            dr["FirstName"].ToString(),
                            dr["MiddleName"].ToString(),
                            dr["Gender"].ToString(),
                            dr["ContactNum"].ToString(),
                            dr["Email"].ToString(),
                            dr["Birthday"].ToString(),
                            dr["BirthPlace"].ToString(),
                            dr["CivilStatus"].ToString(),
                            dr["Address"].ToString());
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Error loading records: " + ex.Message);
        }
        finally
        {
            if (dr != null && !dr.IsClosed)
            {
                dr.Close();
            }
            if (con.State == ConnectionState.Open)
            {
                con.Close();
            }
        }
    }

    private void save_btn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(employeeID_txt.Text) ||
                string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(LastName_txt.Text) ||
                string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(FirstName_txt.Text) ||
                string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(MiddleName_txt.Text) ||
                string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(Gender_txt.Text) ||
                string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(MobileNum_txt.Text) ||
                string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(Email_txt.Text) ||
                string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(Bday_txt.Text) ||
                string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(Bplace_txt.Text) ||
                string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(Status_txt.Text) ||
                string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(Address_txt.Text))
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Please fill out all fields.");
                return; // Exit the method if any field is empty
            }

            con.Open();

            // Check if the ID already exists
            string checkIDQuery = "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Personal_info WHERE EmployeeID = @EmployeeID";
            SqlCommand checkIDCmd = new SqlCommand(checkIDQuery, con);
            checkIDCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@EmployeeID", employeeID_txt.Text);

            int count = (int)checkIDCmd.ExecuteScalar();

            if (count > 0)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("ID already exists. Please use a different ID.");
                return; // Exit the method if ID already exists
            }

            cmd = new SqlCommand("INSERT INTO Personal_info (EmployeeID, LastName, FirstName, MiddleName, Gender, ContactNum, Email, Birthday, BirthPlace, CivilStatus, Address) VALUES (@EmployeeID, @LastName, @FirstName, @MiddleName, @Gender, @ContactNum, @Email, @Birthday, @BirthPlace, @CivilStatus, @Address)", con);

            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@EmployeeID", employeeID_txt.Text);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@LastName", LastName_txt.Text);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@FirstName", FirstName_txt.Text);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@MiddleName", MiddleName_txt.Text);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Gender", Gender_txt.Text);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ContactNum", MobileNum_txt.Text);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Email", Email_txt.Text);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Birthday", Bday_txt.Text);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@BirthPlace", Bplace_txt.Text);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@CivilStatus", Status_txt.Text);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Address", Address_txt.Text);

            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            MessageBox.Show("Employee Details Are Saved.");            
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Error: " + ex.Message);
        }
        finally
        {
            con.Close();
            LoadDataGrid();
        }
    }
}
```

}

I try to add condition for load records and automatically add row when I saved the data but still now showing in my data grid view. than you for help guys!

Answer (score -1):

To avoid adding duplicate rows to your existing datagridview, you may consider using `DataGridView.Rows.Clear()` to clean up your DataGridview before reading the data.

Or verify that the EmployeeID already exists in your `LoadDataGrid()` method to avoid duplicate additions.